# Smartcontract that receive tokens and ether(native BNB) and swap it through pancakeSwap router?

Tags: solidity, tokens, ether

I am creating a smartcontract on BSC which receive specific BSC tokens and transfer it to smartcontract. Then using Pancakeswap router to swap that token to MyOwnToken but I am unable to integrate to receive native BNB, though it works for WBNB.

Any minimal example how to do this?

below is code I am using...

```
//receiving token from user to smartcontract

IBEP20(fromToken).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

//swapping token

function swap(
        address _tokenIn,
        address _tokenOut,
        uint256 _amountIn,
        uint256 _amountOutMin,
        address _to
    ) private {
        //next we need to allow the pancakeswap router to spend the token we just sent to this contract
        //by calling IBEP20 approve you allow the pancakeswap contract to spend the tokens in this contract
        IBEP20(_tokenIn).safeApprove(PANCAKESWAP_ROUTER, _amountIn);

        //path is an array of addresses.
        //this path array will have 3 addresses [tokenIn, WBNB, tokenOut]
        //the if statement below takes into account if token in or token out is WBNB.  then the path is only 2 addresses
        address[] memory path;
        if (_tokenIn == WBNB || _tokenOut == WBNB) {
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = _tokenOut;
        } else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = WBNB;
            path[2] = _tokenOut;
        }

        //then we will call swapExactTokensForTokens
        //for the deadline we will pass in block.timestamp
        //the deadline is the latest time the trade is valid for
        IPancakeRouter(PANCAKESWAP_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOutMin,
            path,
            _to,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `swapExactETHForTokens`, not 100% sure as im typing this on my phone but i believe the syntax is :

```
IPancakeRouter.swapExactETHForTokens({msg.value})(
amountOutMin,
path, //path is WBNB->YourToken
to,
deadline
);
```

Comment: (and ofc your function needs to be payable)

Comment: can I do it with params without payable? because I also want other tokens as input which isn't payable.

Comment: well the function that calls `swapExactETHForTokens` can be non payable if wanted, but it's going to require ETH (BNB in your case) anyways, so you'd need to use BNB already stored in the  contract.

Comment: I want to user to send a BNB as deposit and later swap it tokens.

Comment: Then you need a `recieve()` that provides a way for the contract to keep track of who deposited what (a `mapping(address => uint256)` will do), and your actual swap function can be non payable, but it has to check that the user isnt trying to swap more than what he deposited, and in that case in `IPancakeRouter.swapExactETHForTokens({msg.value})( //... );` just replace `msg.value` with `amount`